# Flexbox flex-direction hiding scroll on Firefox/IE/Edge

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox and flex-direction.
I'm creating a web chat application, everything works as expected on Chrome, but I have a problem with Firefox, IE and Edge browsers.
I have a container:

```
.chat-box-main {
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    overflow: auto;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

and it has `display:flex;` and `flex-direction: column-reverse` properties. I would like to present messages from bottom, not from top that's why it is set to column-reverse.
Everything is okay on Chrome browser, but on Firefox, there is no scrollbar to scroll content of the chat. 
What is interesting, when I change to `flex-direction: column;` everything is okay, but I don't have content switched upside down. This cause some serious problems with scrolling to bottom etc.

I read that this is a problem with Mozilla Firefox, and it is considered as a bug, but is there anyone who found a workaround for this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, try use: flex 1 0 auto

Comment: No luck with that. Looks like it's exactly the same problem from here:
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/108